# Laser in mirror experiment

Tags: eyes, human-eye, light

Apologies if this question is very simple I performed an experiment where I would shine my toy laser at the mirror and it would be reflected.

Now here is what I tried:

I could see my laser toy , I inferred that If I could see it then external Light source must come and hit it such that it falls on the mirror and mirror reflects it back to my eye. So If I shine the laser light on the mirror in the place where my actual laser toy is I could get the laser to be reflected towards my eye.

Hence when I had my two eyes to be open light from laser toy fell on my right eye which I felt was strange. I expected the light to be in the middle because we have both eyes and the light hitting both eyes I thought would average out.

Then I closed my left eye and I could see that It fell on my right eye If I pointed the light where my eyes could see the laser.

I closed my right eye and I could make the light fall on my left eye!

So I had some questions here:
Why is it so that the images we see are inferred from the right eye for me , If we can also get images from the left eye why is right eye's image is taken to be the overall image?
What is the use of left eye in this case ?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obligatory - Don't shine lasers into your eyes, you only have one set and [run the risk of permanent eye damage](https://www.aao.org/eye-health/news/laser-pointer-eye-injury)!

We have [dominant eyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocular_dominance), just like we have dominant hands and feet. This means that with both eyes open, you naturally adjust your hand/eye coordination to compensate so that your dominant eye receives the majority of the input.

A conventional test for this is to get a longish straight tube, such as that found in paper towels or Aluminium foil (AKA tinfoil) or similar (rolled up paper tube works too). Hold this so that with both eyes open you see a clear circle. Now close one eye. Now close that eye and open the other and compare. If you close your dominant eye, you will see that you can no longer see clearly down the tube, but if you close your non-dominant eye, you can still see fully down the tube.